# Blackberry design pattern question:

Tags: java, design-patterns, blackberry

I'm implementing a class that is responsible for all my HTTP requests from the Blackberry. I have around 10 or so screens that use this class to query a web service and get data from it. What would be the standard pattern to use in this case?

Currently I have it setup as follows -

```
public class NetworkAccessClass
{

    public NetworkAccessClass(String url, String methodName, Vector paramNames, Vector paramValues, MainScreen screen) {
        // perform inits
    }

    public void run() {
        // Get Data
        if(screen.instanceOf(LoginScreen)) {
            ((LoginScreen) screen).requestSucceded(responseData);
        }
        // So on for all 10 screens.
        catch() {
            ((LoginScreen) screen).requestFailed(errorCode);
            // So on for all 10 screens.
        }
    }

}
```

It works, but doesn't look right, and if a single screen has multiple types network requests, I'm being forced to add a flag to keep track of which function it's supposed to call back.

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks,
Teja.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a callback interface, e.g. `ResponseHandler`:

```
public class NetworkAccessClass
{

    public interface ResponseHandler {
        void requestSucceeded(ResponseData responseData);
        void requestFailed(ErrorCode errorCode);
    }

    public NetworkAccessClass(
        String url,
        String methodName,
        Vector paramNames,
        Vector paramValues,
        ResponseHandler responseHandler) {
        // perform inits
    }

    public void run() {
        // Get Data
        try {
            ...
            responseHandler.requestSuceeded(responseData);
        catch() {
            responseHandler.requestFailed(errorCode);
        }
    }
}
```

This hopefully decouples your NetworkAccessClass from knowing about all the screens.  Then either your screens implement `NetworkAccessClass.ResponseHandler` or they pass an adapter handler (anonymous inner class) to call the proper methods on the screen, e.g.

```
class LoginScreen {
    ...
        new NetworkAccessClass(url, methodName, paramNames, paramValues,
            new ResponseHandler() {
                @Override
                void requestSucceeded(ResponseData responseData) {
                    LoginScreen.this.handleLoginSuccess(responseData);
                }
                @Override
                void requestFailed(ErrorCode errorCode) {
                    LoginScreen.this.handleLoginFailure(errorCode);
                }
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a listener, which is a simple interface the network class would call back whenever something interesting happens :

```
public interface NetworkListener {
    void requestSucceeded(byte[] responseData);
    void requestFailed(int errorCode);
}

public class NetworkAccess {
    // ...

    public void run() {
        // Get Data
        if (successful) {
            fireSucess(responseData);
        }
        catch(SomeException e) {
            fireFailure(errorCode);
        }
    }

    public void addNetworkListener(NetworkListener listener) {
        // add listener to list of listeners
    }

    private void fireSuccess(byte[] responseData) {
        for (NetworkListener l : listeners) {
            l.requestSucceeded(responseData);
        }
    }

    // ...
}

public class LoginScreen {
    private void foo() {
        NetworkAccess access = new NetworkAccess(...);
        access.addNetworkListener(new NetworkListener() {
            public void requestSucceeded(byte[] responseData) {
                 // do what you want
            }
            public void requestFailed(int errorCode) {
                 // do what you want
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is known as the Observable/observer pattern. The observable notifies its observers when something happens, but without having to know their exact type. The listsner class decouples the two parties.